# Many fields in Protobuf oneof

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is there a performance implication to having a 23-field "oneof" in a protobuf? I'm using proto3.

I am curious particularly about:

1. Are there boolean flags that need to be parsed for each additional oneof field?
2. How is the knowledge about which field is "the one" sent over the wire and processed?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual data being sent down-the-wire? If not, **why not**?

Comment: I had indeed looked at the proto specification. I was unable to figure out a) how optionals were represented and b) how the knowledge about which field was "the one" was transfered, hence my question. I got an answer though which helped clear it up (:

Comment: "the proto specification" is not the same thing as "actual data sent down-the-wire" - I meant you should use a tool like Wireshark, Fiddler, or Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a field number for each one in the wire format, which is how the recipient knows which field has been sent.

There's effectively no consequences arising from having lots of fields. About the only thing that takes more time is probably the length of a switch/case (or similar) statement for each field value.

**Non-Standard Situations**

Oneof's are a bit of an artificial construct anyway - the oneoff-ness is enforced in the class generated from the .proto file, it's not enforced in the wire format. It is possible to send wire format data that has more than one field in it, and all the parser at the receiving end does is silently keep the last one received. You can't send that with the standard generated class (because, it'll have only one field set). Obviously, in this non-standard situation the parser would be having to parse all the received oneoff fields, only to keep just the last one.

So in theory, one could (in a non-standard way) generate parseable wireformat data that would take a long time to parse by having a lot of fields (and repititions of them). This is in contrast to other serialisation standards, where if wireformat of that sort was received the parser would balk at the first hint of there being too many fields and throw an exception / return an error.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely clears things up, most of my confusion (which led to two downvotes lol) was that I thought there had to be some sort of way to know which of the 'oneof' was actually set, and what happens if a faulty client sets multiple of them.

Comment: @cmcnealy No worries :-) Yes, given what GPB allows in the wireformat (like multiple fields), it's buried in the docs that it's the last one that's kept! Personlly speaking I think this behaviour of GPB is pretty poor; the whole idea behind schema driven serialisations is that they're a contract, understood by both ends. With GPB, a recipient of a one-off may have no idea that the sender is sending something different. It's ripe for confusing situations. There's plenty of others that are more thorough, espeically ASN.1 (my go-to for these things, but costs money for good tools). Good luck!